# Rotate file if line limit exceeds 100 lines using linux commands

Tags: linux, unix

I want to rotate the file if lines exceed 100 lines, so which command is suitable to use in linux??
Like split command specifies the max size of the file needed, so which command limits the number of lines and rotates if it exceeds the line limit or like 100lines??

Comment: There is a command rotatelogs which uses the number of mb to limit the data and then rotates the file if it exceed the limit so my doubt is which command to use if we have to put a limit on the number of lines

Comment: If you're looking for a linux command, try posting on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).